# Highest runs scored by the lowest scoring batsman in a full innings in test cricket

Tags: cricket, records

Considering all the lowest individual scores scored during a full innings (All 10 wickets fall), what is the highest among those? i.e, the greatest number of runs scored by the lowest scoring batsman of the team? Which match did this happen and what was the result of this match?

I'm primarily interested in test cricket, but also answers referring to first class cricket, one day or Twenty20 would be of interest.

Comment: What type of cricket? What standard? You'll need to focus the question a lot before it stops being too broad for an answer.

Comment: Fair point. I guess I was thinking about international test cricket, but if anyone has info on other first class cricket matches, also one day/20Twenty I'd also be interested. I was just browsing records and noted that I only ever saw record total scores of the whole team. That's great, but often that score is mostly generated by 2 or 3 players in the team. I thought it would be interesting to see what the best performances in which every player played a significant scoring role was. For this a measure like the best median score or the best lowest score could be good to see.

Comment: OK, I suggest you edit to question to say test cricket. At the moment it's phrased in a way that would include under-9 cricket on the Isle of Wight, which is a wee bit too broad!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The highest low score of an innings in Test matches is [12](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;groupby=innings;orderby=start;orderbyad=reverse;qualmin1=10;qualmin2=11;qualval1=outs;qualval2=innings;runsmin1=12;runsval1=runs;template=results;type=batting).

[image: Screenshot of Statsguru of all Test innings with a lowest individual score of at least 12 runs]

As can be seen in the screenshot, this low score has been made on two occasions. The first was by [India in the first Test against New Zealand in Dunedin in 1967/68](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/63019.html), where [Bapu Kulkarni](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/31760.html) was lbw to New Zealand's fast-medium bowler [Bruce Taylor](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/38609.html) for 12 in the second innings of the match, which India would go on to win by five wickets. The second was much more recent: in the first innings of the [third Test between England and South Africa at Johannesburg in 2015/16](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/800465.html), South Africa's [Morné Morkel](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/46538.html) was last man out for 12, caught by English captain [Alastair Cook](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/11728.html) off the fast bowling of allrounder [Ben Stokes](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/player/311158.html). South Africa went on to lose crushingly by seven wickets. In both cases, the players had made the lowest scores of their respective team innings.

The Bash command used to find this information was:

```
i=0;while ! (wget "http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;groupby=innings;orderby=start;orderbyad=reverse;qualmin1=10;qualmin2=11;qualval1=outs;qualval2=innings;runsmin1=${i};runsval1=runs;size=1;template=results;type=batting" -O- -q | grep 'No records available to match this query' >/dev/null 2>&1);do i="$((${i}+1))";done;i="$((${i}-1))";wget "http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;groupby=innings;orderby=start;orderbyad=reverse;qualmin1=10;qualmin2=11;qualval1=outs;qualval2=innings;runsmin1=${i};runsval1=runs;size=200;template=results;type=batting" -O- -q | grep '^ *<td colspan="[^">]\+">' | grep -o '[>][^<]\+[<]' | tr -d '<>';echo "SCORE: ${i}"
```

Comment: Your cricinfo skills are much better than mine. I can never get anything useful out of their stats machine :-) Is it possible to link to the query you generated rather than just a screenshot so people can modify it and play around with it?

Comment: The "12" in the first sentence links to the Statsguru query screenshotted, and I have added the Bash command that was used to find the information.

Comment: Good answer thanks! You are indeed a master cricinfo stat extractor :)!

It's less than I imagined it would be. Interesting that in both those cases the score from the whole innings was, at best, average. This is clearly a very bad indicator of a teams performance in an innings, even if it may be a better indicator of the extent to which the whole team contributed to the number of runs scored. It would be interesting to see the highest median score, but I imagine this data is even harder to extract.

Answer (score 4):

In ODI cricket the highest lowest individual score in an all-out innings is **8**, obtained twice: by [Kenya against Zimbabwe in 2009](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/13458/scorecard/424849/Zimbabwe-vs-Kenya-1st-ODI-Kenya-tour-of-Zimbabwe-2009-10) (Kenya lost by 91 runs) and by [India against Australia in 1983](http://audiodata.cricinfo.com/db/ARCHIVE/WORLD_CUPS/WC83/GROUP-B/IND_AUS_WC83_ODI23_20JUN1983.html) (India won by 118 runs).

In T20I cricket, it's **2**: [Zimbabwe against Afghanistan in 2016](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8604/scorecard/951321/Afghanistan-vs-Zimbabwe-9th-Match,-First-Round-Group-B-World-T20-2015-16) (Zimbabwe lost by 59 runs) and by [New Zealand against Sri Lanka in 2009](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8604/scorecard/356013/New-Zealand-vs-Sri-Lanka-23rd-Match,-Group-F-ICC-World-Twenty20-2009) (New Zealand lost by 48 runs).

In first class cricket it's **22**: [Yorkshire against Leicestershire in 1907](http://audiodata.cricinfo.com/db/ARCHIVE/1900S/1907/ENG_LOCAL/CC/LEICS_YORKS_CC_27-29JUN1907.html) in the 1st innings (match drawn).

In List A cricket it's **10**: Brothers Union against [Abahani Limited in 2013](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8738/scorecard/682263/Abahani-Limited-vs-Brothers-Union--Dhaka-Premier-Division-2013-14) (Brothers Union lost by 27 runs).

In T20 cricket it's **4** on four occasions: [here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8803/scorecard/342329/Centrals-vs-Easterns-(Zimbabwe)--Metropolitan-Bank-Twenty20-2007-08), [here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/australia/engine/match/298387.html), [here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8053/scorecard/225303/Lancashire-vs-Derbyshire--Twenty20-Cup-2006) and [here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8661/scorecard/902097/Saurashtra-vs-Tripura-Group-B-Syed-Mushtaq-Ali-Trophy-2015-16).

Comment: I am curious as to how you got the data for First-Class, List A, and T20 cricket.

Comment: All scorecard info can be found on Cricinfo and CricketArchive